# Can the limiting process be used to differentiate $f(x)=x$?

Tags: calculus

If so, then why is $dy/dx=0$?

Slope=$∆x/∆x=1$

$\lim_{∆x\to0} ∆x/∆x=0$

Therefore $dx/dx$ should be $0$. Is this right, if not pls correct.

Comment: That means it tends to that value, it's not exactly equal to 0

Comment: What makes you think that $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x}$ goes to $0$ as $\Delta x$ goes to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement you made in the question is not correct:

```
Slope=$∆x/∆x$
```

The slope is of the curve is (change in y over the change in x):

$$∆y/∆x$$

```
Can the limiting process be used to differentiate  f(x)=x ?
```

Yes of course. Using the chart below, you want to find the limit as x approaches zero for the expression:

$$\frac{x+∆x-x}{∆x}$$

$$ f'(x)=\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{x+∆x-x}{∆x}=1=dy/dx$$

```
Therefore $dx/dx$ should be 0.
```

Not so because the the derivative is actually $dy/dx=1$ from the above. This tells us that the rate of change for this function is constant and is always = $1$ for all $x$ values in its domain.

All of these things are well described in many good Calculus books.
[image]

Ref:
[Image Source](https://www.themathpage.com/aCalc/derivative.htm)

Answer (score 2):

**What is $\frac{0}{0}$? It is not zero.**

The expression $\Delta x/ \Delta x$ is always equal to one, except for $\Delta x=0$ where it is not defined. When looking for the limit, you assume that $\Delta x\neq0$. In general, when looking for the limit of a function you always assume that the variable is not equal to the value it approaches. That is what limits are for - for us to get around the fact that a function is not defined at some point.

Because $\Delta x/\Delta x$ is $1$ however close $\Delta x$ comes to $0$ (but not being equal to $0$), the limit is $$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{ h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)} {h}.$

Your argument is not correct. You should have $\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac {\Delta x} {\Delta x} = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that $\frac{\delta x}{\delta x}$ converges to 0 as $\delta x$ approaches 0. This can easily be verified by l'hopitals rule, since you get an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Perhaps the most intuitive way to think of limits is through the definition of what it means to be a limit. When you say $f(x)\rightarrow a$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ what you should think of is what happens to f(x) near a (but not at a, this is important) as x approaches 0. I suggest you look up the formal definition of a limit.